# unable to install matplotlib in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I am using the OS Ubuntu 20.04 and I have installed Anaconda Python. I am following a course in orielly and the instructor asked to execute the below 2 commands, on trying it I am getting the respective error message,

**command:**

```
jupyter labextension install jupyter-matplotlib
```

**error:**

```
An error occured.
ValueError: "jupyter-matplotlib" is not a valid npm package
```

**command** :

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

**error:**

```
An error occured.
ValueError: "@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager" is not a valid npm package
```

I have installed nodejs already, for your information.

Answer (score 0):

Open Anaconda prompt and just run the command:

```
pip update --all
pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: But there is no anaconda prompt installed in Ubuntu. I think this anaconda prompt will be available for windows.